# Installing NFS in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian-stretch, nfs

I read a lot of articles and it seems it should be pretty simple to install NFS in Raspbian. Just installed the three packages rpcbind nfs-common nfs-kernel-server and I'm getting this error:

```
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Mounting NFSD configuration filesystem...
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Preprocess NFS configuration...
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to mount NFSD configuration filesystem.
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS Mount Daemon.
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFSv4 ID-name mapping service.
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nfs-idmapd.service: Job nfs-idmapd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nfs-mountd.service: Job nfs-mountd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Unit entered failed state.
Oct  4 00:04:37 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Preprocess NFS configuration.
Oct  4 00:04:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reloading.
```

I also found a lot of bugreports related to these messages but none seem to apply to my specific situation. Any idea what this may be about? Thanks!

Comment: `none seem to apply to my specific situation` what is your specific situation? If the bug reports relate to the messages, then how is your situation different?

Comment: There were many reports around, describing how each was not applying seemed to require a bit. Sometimes the report was related to a older version than the one I have. Other times changes to systemd files I do not have were suggested, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the root cause of the problem. A single reboot was however sufficient to make NFS work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Jessie systemd service had a known bug, but this is now fixed.

The only thing you have to do under Stretch is install nfs-kernel-server - this now seems to have a proper systemd service, and rpcbind is now included by default.

You do have to configure `/etc/exports` to export home directory.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=176765&hilit=nfs#p1211260

Comment: So what is the package you are suggesting to install?